# RecycleView with different view types

Tags: android

I have RecycleView which has two almost the same views (the same content but in different orders). They have different ViewHolders so I can instatiate the different layouts but the rest is the same. So I would like not to repeat myself because it's a bad practice. Here is my code:

```
class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    PostItemBinding mViewDataBinding;

    public ViewHolder(PostItemBinding viewDataBinding) {
        super(viewDataBinding.getRoot());
        mViewDataBinding = viewDataBinding;
        mViewDataBinding.executePendingBindings();
    }

    public PostItemBinding getBinding() {
        return mViewDataBinding;
    }
}

// ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

class ViewHolderComments extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    PostWithCommentItemBinding mViewDataBinding;

    public ViewHolderComments(PostWithCommentItemBinding viewDataBinding) {
        super(viewDataBinding.getRoot());
        mViewDataBinding = viewDataBinding;
        mViewDataBinding.executePendingBindings();
    }

    public PostWithCommentItemBinding getBinding() {
        return mViewDataBinding;
    }
}


@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final RecyclerView.ViewHolder base, final int pos) {

    if (base instanceof ViewHolder) {

        position = hideHeader ? pos : pos - 1;
        setUpPostView(base, position);

    } else if (base instanceof ViewHolderComments) {

        position = hideHeader ? pos : pos - 1;
        setUpCommentsView(base, position);

    } else {

        setUpHeader(base);
    }
}
```

The first view setup:

```
    protected void setUpPostView(RecyclerView.ViewHolder base, final int position) {

                final ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder) base;

                ..... the same code
}
```

The second view setup:

```
protected void setUpCommentsView(RecyclerView.ViewHolder base, final int position) {

            final ViewHolderComments holder = (ViewHolderComments) base;

            ..... the same code
}
```

Without the first line where I cast the ViewHolder everything is the same. How I can optimize/improve it? Using Abstract Class?

Comment: Depending on your needs you might benefit from using something like https://github.com/afollestad/sectioned-recyclerview

Comment: use OOP's basics like inheritance ... fx class `ViewHolderBase` with `setup(int position)` and inherit from it

Comment: What is the difference between ViewHolder and ViewHolderComments?

Comment: They have different bindings.

Comment: If both methods have the same code why don't you pass RecyclerView.ViewHolder base? And avoid casting altogether? If it is not possible then you should maybe create a super class, where you put stuff that is the same and then pass this class as a parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: you can try this code, I assume that `PostItemBinding` and `PostWithCommentItemBinding` are both extends from `ViewDataBinding`

```
class BaseHolder<T extends ViewDataBinding> extends ViewHolder<T> {
    T mViewDataBinding;

    public BaseHolder(T viewDataBinding) {
        super(viewDataBinding.getRoot());
        mViewDataBinding = viewDataBinding;
        mViewDataBinding.executePendingBindings();
    }

    public T getBinding() {
        return mViewDataBinding;
    }

    public void setupView(int position) {
        // your same code
    }
}

class ViewHolder extends BaseHolder<PostItemBinding> {

    public ViewHolder(PostItemBinding viewDataBinding) {
        super(viewDataBinding);
    }
}

class ViewHolderComments extends BaseHolder<PostWithCommentItemBinding> {

    public ViewHolderComments(PostWithCommentItemBinding viewDataBinding) {
        super(viewDataBinding);
    }
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final RecyclerView.ViewHolder base, final int pos) {
    if (base instanceof BaseHolder) {
        position = hideHeader ? pos : pos - 1;
        ((BaseHolder) base).setupView(position);
    }  else {
        setUpHeader(base);
    }
}
```

With proper `getItemViewType` and `onCreateViewHolder`, you might just only need `BaseHolder` class and can remove the `ViewHolder` class and `ViewHolderComments` class, but it's base on yours remaining code.

Comment: My problem is only with the repeat of code everything else is working. But the one holder has a binding of type PostBinding and the other one of type PostWithCommentBinding. So I cannot cast ViewHolder (which is for Post) to ViewHolderComments(which is for Post with comment). I will add the holders so to be more clear.

Comment: @ionicorn I updated my answer, pls check if it may help you, to answer your question simply: you need to use an Abstract class here

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to use a different viewholder for it, you can initiate the same viewholder class with a different source layout and just add a flag in the holder.

```
class MyViewHolder {
    public static final int TYPE_POST = 1;
    public static final int TYPE_COMMENT = 2;
    public int type;
}
```

Return `TYPE_POST` or `TYPE_COMMENT` in `getItemType`, set the variable in the `onCreateViewHolder` to the holder. `onBindViewHolder` you can simply cast to `MyViewHolder` and check the `type` variable, and depending on that you can access different fields or other stuff.

You can also create a parent viewholder class and have two sub-viewholders that extend the one. You wouldn't need the type variable in this case, but instead have inheritance.

Comment: When I use the same ViewHolder I receive databinding.PostWithCommentItemBinding cannot be cast to databinding.PostItemBinding where post_item is the xml for my first design and post_with_comment for my second one

Comment: You should have added the databinding part from the beginning, as this was not clear.

Answer (score 0):

You have to implement the method: getItemViewType(int position) on your Adapter.

like this:

```
@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    switch(position) {
        case 0:
            return POST;
        default:
            return COMMENT;
    }
}


@Override
public YourViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    switch (viewType) {
        case POST:
            //// create view holder for: R.layout.row_post;
            break;
        case COMMENT:
            //// create view holder for: R.layout.row_comment;
            break;
    }

   ....
}
```

Comment: I have getItemViewType and onCreateViewHolder methods and I do not have problem with that. I just do not want to have two different methods with the same content only because of the casting on the first line.